# Does feature normalization improve performance of Hidden Markov Models?

Tags: preprocessing, normalization, markov-hidden-model, expectation-maximization

For training a Hidden Markov Model (HMM) on a multivariate, continuous time series, is it preferable to scale the data somehow? Some pre-processing steps may be:

1. Normalize to 0-mean and unit-variance
2. Scale to [-1, 1] interval
3. Scale to [0, 1] interval

With neural networks, [the rationale behind scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28191414/4591810) is to get an "un-squished" error surface that is easier to navigate in.

HMMs use the [Baum-Welch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum%E2%80%93Welch_algorithm), which is a variation on the [Expectation Maximization (EM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) algorithm, to learn parameters.

Is EM sensitive to scale of features? Is there some motivation for normalization for HMMs?